# Send and Receive packets from same TCP port

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have two custom programs that one sends a stream of data and other one receive that stream for further processing. Is it possible to send data to a one TCP port and receive(read) that data from the same port ?. If not can you recommend any alternative method.Any help will is appreciated.
(The two programs run on the same machine)

Comment: do you mean 'is it possible to send data from a TCP port and receive the data from the same port?'

Comment: Since both programs are running on the same machine, you don't have to use sockets (they are meant to be used between machines, but can be used also on the same machine), you can use other means for [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) such as pipes or unix sockets

Comment: @Legman .yeah I missed the question mark.

Comment: @EarthDragon I will look in to that. thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the two ends of the same TCP connection? One end's sending port will always be the other end's receiving port and vice versa.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, I want the connection and communication to be implemented like that

Comment: @Rdoz They *are* implemented like that. TCP sockets are full-duplex.

Comment: Why do you want to use the *same port* on the *same machine* ?  Typical TCP implementation is that client (the one that calls `connect`) picks a random port to connect from and the server (the one that calls `accept`) listens on a pre-defined port.

Answer (score 2):

A TCP connection has two ends and permits communication in both directions. Each end's sending port is the other end's receiving port. That is always the case.

If you're asking if each end's sending port can be the same as the other end's receiving port, the answer is yes. That's always the case.

If you're asking if both ends can have the same sending and receiving port, the answer is:

1) If the source IP address is the same on both ends (say `127.0.0.1`) then absolutely not. If they could be, it would be impossible to distinguish between the two endpoints.

2) If the source IP address is different on both sends (say `127.0.0.2` on one end and `127.0.0.3` on the other) this is theoretically possible and can easily happen if you're using two different machines. But so far as I know, no common TCP/IP stack permits a single port to be used in this way if both ends are on the same machine. Once you're listening on a port, you are not permitted to use that port as a source port. And if you're using a port as a source port, you're not permitted to begin listening on it.

But I get the feeling that you're asking the wrong question. If you clarified what you're trying to do and why, you might get an answer to a different question that would be of more help to you.

Comment: You can use the same port locally if they are bound to different local IP addresses that aren't 0.0.0.0, but whether they can communicate is another question.

Comment: So maybe `bind(127.0.0.1:9999); listen()` on one end and `bind(127.0.0.2:9999); connect(127.0.0.1:9999)` on the other end?